# OS X 10.6 services - how to force reindexing

Tags: macos, service

I have an application installed on OS X 10.6 which offers some services when a file or directory is selected in the Finder. After moving the application to trash, the service entries are still shown in the Finder.

How to force OS X to "reindex" the known services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `pbs` (the paste board server) to reset it:

```
$ /System/Library/CoreServices/pbs
```

see [this Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/SysServices/Articles/providing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000853-SW2).

Or, empty the trash.